# Include if/else logic

Tags: powershell, outlook

Hello I am trying to `if/else` and write two separate files, `if` `PST` exists then do the following. `Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\$UserName-$ComputerName-OpenPSTs-$Date.csv`

`Else` `Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\$UserName-$ComputerName-NOPSTs-$Date.csv`

Could anyone please suggest.

```
$Date = Get-Date -format d-M-yyyy
$UserName = $env:USERNAME
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$Outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application

$object = $Outlook.Session.Stores | Where {$_.FilePath -like "*.PST"} | Select `
@{Expression={$_.DisplayName}; Label="PST Name in Outlook"},`
@{Expression={$_.FilePath}; Label="PST Location/FileName"},`
@{Expression={$_.IsOpen}; Label="PST Open in Outlook"},`
@{Expression={(Get-Item $_.FilePath).Length / 1KB}; Label="PST File Size (KB)"}
$object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'ComputerName' -Value $ComputerName
$object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'UserName' -Value $UserName
$object | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\$UserName-$ComputerName-OpenPSTs-$Date.csv

Start-Sleep 5
Get-Process | Where {$_.Name -like "Outlook*"} | Stop-Process
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the `Where-Object` filter with a `ForEach-Object` loop and a nested conditional:

```
$Outlook.Session.Stores | % {
  if ($_.FilePath -like '*.pst') {
    $_ | select ... | Export-Csv 'OpenPST.csv' -NoType -Append
  } else {
    $_ | select ... | Export-Csv 'NoPST.csv' -NoType -Append
  }
}
```

That might not perform too well, though, because it repeatedly appends to the output files. It might be better to just run 2 pipelines with complementary filters:

```
$stores = $Outlook.Session.Stores

$stores | ? { $_.FilePath -like '*.pst' } | select ... |
    Export-Csv 'OpenPST.csv' -NoType
$stores | ? { $_.FilePath -notlike '*.pst' } | select ... |
    Export-Csv 'NoPST.csv' -NoType
```